# Kendo-ui Scheduler disable event edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, scheduler

I am using kendo-ui scheduler and have events created. Is there any way to disable the default edit popup when double click on event. Because I have a custom edit event popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Edit event and create a function with the condition that will allow or not to edit.

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
      views: [ "day", "month" ],
      dataSource: [
        {
          id: 1,
          start: new Date("2021/9/6 08:00 AM"),
          end: new Date("2021/9/6 09:00 AM"),
          title: "test event"
        }
      ],
      edit: function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           if(yourCondition === false){
              // do something else
           } else {
             // open the edit window
              
           }
        
      }
    });
```

About open event edit window https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ActionSheetEventBuilder#opensystemstring